# Unable to connect to AWS Elasticsearch instance from EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and an Elasticsearch instance in the same vpc. I am trying to connect via requests_aws4auth package and python elasticsearch connector.

```
host = cfg.AWS_HOST # For example, my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
region = cfg.AWS_REGION # e.g. us-west-1

service = 'es'

awsauth = AWS4Auth(cfg.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, cfg.AWS_SECRET_KEY, region, service)

es = Elasticsearch(
hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
http_auth = awsauth,
use_ssl = True,
verify_certs = True,
connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)
```

I am getting this **ERROR** when trying to connect

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writeData.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(es.info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 241, in info
    return self.transport.perform_request('GET', '/', params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 90, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status_code, raw_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthorizationException: AuthorizationException(403, u'{"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}')
```

Comment: Have you verified that your EC2 Instance Profile has permissions to call es? And that your AES permission policy allows your instance profile to call it?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to pass the session_token information too as a parameter.

Like this..

```
auth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, 
              region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
```

as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-an-easy-way-to-send-aws-sigv4-signed-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting within the same VPC, you do not want to use the external host address. Instead, use the internal ip of the elastic machine or an internal load balancer depending on your ES setup.